# Proving equivalence of tropical polynomials

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, tropical-geometry, tropical-arithmetic

I am new to the world of tropical mathematics. I am wondering if there is an algorithm to prove the equivalence of two tropical polynomials (in the plus-min semiring let's say), say over multivaribles? If one restricts oneself to integers (or even natural numbers), is the problem simpler?